# Executing shell script on wamp

Tags: php, shell, windows-7, exec, wamp

My pc at work run windows 7, but I need to emulate a unix server to run a working shell script on php exec() command. I installed cygwin but I have no idea how can I make the php execute cigwin for him to therefore execute my shell script.

Comment: You should really get a Linux/UNIX computer.  Cygwin isn't nearly good enough to run an average shell script.  Visualization is also an option (run a UNIX OS as a guest).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand you meant virtualization. Also +1 for getting a linux/unix computer, be it real or virtualized

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós I like to visualize all my computers. I can see them now, doing what I ask them to and nothing else. We all need dreams...

Comment: I am wondering the very same question and I would like to know how to do it. I have a virtual box environement working also but sometimes I use a pc and I have collaborators that uses pc so I believe it would be legitimate to provide an answer to that question.